# Como puedo limitar los caracteres del título de wordpress y si se pasa que aparezca un (...)

Tags: php, wordpress

¿Cómo puedo limitar los caracteres del titulo de wordpress para que si se pasa  de un límite aparezca `(...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Si que seria posible, para eso tendrías que modificar el loop de wordpress, específicamente en la parte donde están los títulos por esto:

```
<?php $title = get_the_title(); if ( strlen( $title ) > 15 ) { 

    $title_short = substr( $title, 0, 15 );
    echo  '' . $title_short . '...';

} else {

    echo $title;

} ?>
```

La primera linea verifica el numero de caracteres que contiene un titulo, si es mayor a 15 muestra los primeros 15 caracteres mas los tres puntos, si es menor a 15 caracteres entonces solo muestra el titulo.

Posiblemente haya varias formas de hacerlo, con esto puede hacerse una idea.